# How do I delete DOM element on a button click

Tags: javascript, html

```
function removeDOM() {
debugger;
alert('sahd');
}

<div style="padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;border:solid;border-color:black;border-width:thin;width:350px;height:75px;" id="divv">
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(); return false;" />
    </div>
```

Above is my code which renders three labels and three buttons. If I click on the first button, then the `Abcd1` label should get deleted.

Can I use use the following code inside my `removeDOM` function?

```
$(this).parents('label').remove();
```

Comment: you need `.prev().remove()`

Comment: @Petroff: There's no `jquery` tag here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the clicked element to the function

```
<div style="padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;border:solid;border-color:black;border-width:thin;width:350px;height:75px;" id="divv">
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
</div>
```

then

```
function removeDOM(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el.previousElementSibling)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jzw6Lw9f/) - supported IE >= 9

Comment: @chsdk it is `previousElementSibling` not `previousSibling`

Answer (score 0):

Update your `onclick`s to pass `this` into the function:

```
onclick="removeDOM(this); return false"
```

...then within `removeDOM`, you can use the argument's `previousSibling` or `previousElementSibling`property.

```
function removeDOM(element) {
    element.previousElementSibling.remove();
}
```

That assumes that the sibling is there. If it may not be:

```
function removeDOM(element) {
    if (element.previousElementSibling) {
        element.previousElementSibling.remove();
    }
}
```

Live example:

```js
function removeDOM(element) {
    if (element.previousElementSibling) {
        element.previousElementSibling.remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;border:solid;border-color:black;border-width:thin;width:350px;height:75px;" id="divv">
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
</div>
```

If you need to support older browsers, they may not have `previousElementSibling` or `remove`, which complicates things:

```
function removeDOM(element) {
    var prev;
    for (prev = element.previousSibling; prev; prev = prev.previousSibling) {
        if (prev.nodeType === 1) { // Element
            prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Live example:

```js
function removeDOM(element) {
    var prev;
    for (prev = element.previousSibling; prev; prev = prev.previousSibling) {
        if (prev.nodeType === 1) { // Element
            prev.parentNode.removeChild(prev);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-top:8px;padding-left:5px;border:solid;border-color:black;border-width:thin;width:350px;height:75px;" id="divv">
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
    <label>Abcd1</label>
    <input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [**element.previousSibling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling), try the following code:

```
  function removeDOM(button) {
    var previuosLabel;
    // always remove the white space between the button and the label
    while((button.previousSibling).nodeType !== 1) { 
            button.parentNode.removeChild((button.previousSibling));
    } 
    previuosLabel=button.previousSibling;
    if(previuosLabel.nodeType === 1) { 
        button.parentNode.removeChild(previuosLabel);
    }  
  }
```

Then call it like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="removeDOM(this); return false;" />
```

That will always check if there's a white space between the `button` and the `label` and removes it before removing the `label`, in that case you make sure the label will be removed.

[**Here is a working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5hmacmw/)